# Display multipledimensional array in Twig: impossible to access the key

Tags: php, twig

I have an array which i want to display inside Twig.

#### This is the array:

```
$Products= array(
    '0'=> array(
        '0'=> 'apple',
        '1'=> '1',
        '2'=> 'warehousename',
        '3'=> '34.54'  
    ),
    '1' => array(
        '0'=> 'mango',
        '1'=> '3',
        '2'=> 'warehousename',
        '3'=> '33.3'  
    ),
    '2' => array(
        '0'=> 'orange',
        '1'=> '5',
        '2'=> 'warehousename',
        '3'=> '73.4'  
    )
);
```

#### Twig:

```
{% for Product in Products%}
 <tr>
    {% if Product.1 in ['0','1','3'] %}
    <td>{{ Product }}  </td>
    {% endif %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

> ERROR: impossible to access the key "1"

Comment: Is your array complete ? Because you don't have the key number 3.

Comment: @Pauloscorps I don't think that matters in this case, because the OP is trying to access the sub-key `3`, which is inside `Product`.

Comment: What is the problem here? You mention the error, but what are you expecting? Which elements from `Products` do you want in the view?

Comment: Maybe it's `Product[3]`?

Comment: Ohh my mistake its key "1" and not "3"

Comment: i want to display all the elements inside the table  if the value product.1 exists in [0,1,3]

Comment: like  this : `<tr><td>apple</td>1<td>warehousename</td><td>34.54</td></tr>`

Comment: `{% for key, Product in Products if key == 1 %}` But that doesn't make any sense... You should pass the correct product to the view, instead of passing a collection